# Using translate field for 'unique' rises NameError, django-parler

Tags: django, django-parler

I've recently installed `django-parler==2.2` and when I rewrite my model to inherit from `TranslatableModel` and then try to `makemigrations` I get the following error:

`main_menu_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=main_menu_item)`
`NameError: name 'main_menu_item' is not defined`

Everything runs fine when I inherit from `models.Model`. Here is the code:

```
class MenuItem(TranslatableModel):

    translations = TranslatedFields (
        main_menu_item = models.CharField(max_length=60),
        main_menu_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=main_menu_item)
    )
```

I've just started using this module, so possibly it is something trivial but I couldn't find the solution. What I am doing wrong?

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\project\alfa\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\project\alfa\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\project\alfa\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\project\alfa\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\project\alfa\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\project\alfa\project\menus\models.py", line 16, in <module>
    class MenuItem(TranslatableModel):
  File "C:\project\alfa\project\menus\models.py", line 20, in MenuItem
    main_menu_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=main_menu_item)
NameError: name 'main_menu_item' is not defined
```

Working code `models.Model`:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    main_menu_item = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    main_menu_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=main_menu_item)
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: @schillingt added

Comment: What are you trying to set for `unique`? It looks like a method, but it's supposed to be a boolean value.

Comment: I want to achieve for `slug` to be unique for `main_menu_item`. I added the code which worked.

Comment: @schillingt Will `unique=True` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique` should be a boolean value as per the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: I didn't bother to look in the docs because my learning source used field for `unique` and I took that for granted. What a mistake, it makes sense now. Thank you for answer.